# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, electron-builder

I am stuck for weeks with my electron-angular app running locally but not on the VM it should be deployed in with this error message:

[image: The application was enable to start correctly]

Has anyone encountered this error ?

Here is the electron-builder.json

```
{
    "productName": "MyApp",
    "directories": {
        "output": "C:-path-to-output"
    },
    "files": [
        "**/*",
        "!**/*.ts",
        "!*.code-workspace",
        "!LICENSE.md",
        "!package.json",
        "!package-lock.json",
        "!src/",
        "!e2e/",
        "!hooks/",
        "!angular.json",
        "!_config.yml",
        "!karma.conf.js",
        "!tsconfig.json",
        "!tslint.json"
    ],
    "win": {
        "icon": "dist",
        "target": [
            "portable"
        ],
        "requestedExecutionLevel": "highestAvailable"
     },
     "mac": {
         "icon": "dist",
         "target": [
             "dmg"
         ]
     },
     "linux": {
         "icon": "dist",
         "target": [
             "AppImage"
         ]
     },
     "asarUnpack": [
         "./server",
         "./src/app/configs"
     ]
}
```

Here is my local environment:

- Windows 10 Entreprise (64-bit x64 processor)
- Node.js v12.14.1
- Npm V6.13.4
- Electron v7.1.7
- Electron-Builder V22.5.1
- Angular V8.2

And here is my VM environment:

- Windows 10 Entreprise (64-bit x64 processor)
- Node.js v12.20.1
- Npm v6.14.10

Comment: anything in your event viewer? error details [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_licensing/windows-activation-error-0xc0000022/67ca9093-346b-4a8b-bb07-1870480152bd)

Comment: Are you building the electron app in VM or running the exe file already built in local?

Comment: @Rupjyoti I built the exe in local and run the exe in VM

Comment: Might be some dependency (dll) or permission issue or compatibility issue. You can try to install "process monitor" in VM and check if app tries to run. Also check if the exe is 64bit or not.

Comment: What if you exclude `requestedExecutionLevel`?